# Run python script using another python interpreter through the subuprocess module?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Say I have a simple Hello_World.py script that will write a text file saying hello world.

```
import csv,sys

def main(fname):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Hello World'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    main(fname)
```

I can execute this from the command prompt for a specific python environment using

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe D:\Scripts\hello_world.py D:\Data\test.txt
```

However, how can i execute the same line of code from within another python version using for example the subprocess module? i.e. the following returns a non-zero exit status 1.

```
subprocess.check_call([r'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe',r'D:\Scripts\hello_world.py', r'D:\Data\test.txt'])
```

Definately not the most elegant approach but I unfortunately require the script to be run on a different python version. It would appear that there is some sort of error in calling python.exe considering that this will also fail

```
os.system(r'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe')
```

Comment: You can get more information with `run`. If you capture output then the exception object's `stdout` and `stderr` should be interesting. `subprocess.run([r'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe',r'D:\Scripts\hello_world.py', r'D:\Data\test.txt'], capture_output=True, check=True)`

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately that does not yield anything more and simple returns '''returned non-zero exit status 1'''

Comment: @GeoPy I tried your code myself, and it works for me. I did remove the csv import and thus, instead of `writerow`, run a simple `write`; but I was still able to run the script via the subprocess call without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I did not have permission access to the specified C folder. Why the subprocess.CalledProcessError function did not throw a permissionerror, I do not know.

Comment: The permission error happens inside the subprocess, which is self-contained as far as exceptions and errors go -- from the outside, all that can be seen is that the subprocess completed or failed with a certain exit code (which is raised as a`subprocess.CalledProcessError`, if non-zero). This is why it's generally a good idea to track at least `stderr` when working with subprocesses.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortuantely, this appraoch did not resolve my problem for a completely different reason .  The subprocess executes the new python interpreter successfully however the new interpreter keeps the libraries from the old interpreter for some reason. I may need to start a new question for this though.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know what exactly is going wrong in your script without more information (it seems to be running fine for me?).
To get more details on what is happening, you should try to get access to the process `stdout` and `stderr` streams, as suggested in the comments.

This can be achieved using something like the following script :

```py
import subprocess

try:
    proc = subprocess.run(
        [
            r'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe', 
            r'D:\Scripts\hello_world.py', 
            r'D:\Data\test.txt'
        ],
        capture_output=True,
        check=True
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as proc_err:
    print("An exception occurred in the subprocess: \n ", proc_err)
    print("stdout : \n", proc_err.stdout.decode())
    print("stderr : \n", proc_err.stderr.decode())
    exit(1)

print("stdout : \n", proc.stdout.decode())
print("stderr : \n", proc.stderr.decode())
```